# Get & Set "text" of SVG Text object created with Snap SVG having "textpath" attribute

Tags: javascript, svg, raphael, snap.svg

It's easy to read and update `<text>` element's text property by Snap.SVG

```
var paper = Snap(400, 400);
var t = paper.text(10, 10, 'Lorem Ipsum');
// change text simpy by changing 'text' attribute
t.attr('text', 'New Text');
```

Suppose, if we have a `textpath` attribute attached to text element.

If we do "`t.attr('text', 'New Text');`"
It destroys `<textpath>` child of parent `<text>` element.

Check fiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/JayKandari/476n8t82/

My question is, do we have any Plugin(or code) which can be used to update & read any kind(both simple & nested) of SVG text object. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think its so much a bug, as understanding whats happening behind the scenes.

When you create a text element, you do have a text attribute. However, with SVG, when you create a textPath, that text moves to the textPath element. So you actually have to query the textPath element, which is what Duopixel does.

You can create a plugin to help a bit, but it kinda does the same thing as Duopixels solution...

```
Snap.plugin( function( Snap, Element, Paper, global ) {
    Element.prototype.textPathText = function( text ) {
            return text ? this.select('textPath').node.textContent=text :  this.select('textPath').node.textContent;
    };
});

alert(t.textPathText())
t.textPathText('Snap is still awesome')
alert(t.textPathText())
```

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/476n8t82/3/)

Or this may work for both text and textPath

```
Snap.plugin( function( Snap, Element, Paper, global ) {
    Element.prototype.innerText = function( text ) {
            return text ? this.node.firstChild.textContent=text :  this.node.firstChild.textContent;
    };
});
```

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/476n8t82/5/)

Comment: Nice Idea. But, I think the plugin should be able to handle both types of textobjects. Plugin currently handles objects having textpath only.

Comment: Works Grt @Ian. I think this feature should get pushed to orig Snap library.

Answer (score 0):

This seems like a bug in SnapSVG. You could switch to plain JS/DOM to perform the gets/sets:

```
var paper = Snap(400, 400);

var t = paper.text(0,20, 'Snap.SVG is awesome !');

t.attr({textpath : 'M10,10L300,300'});
var textPath = t.node.querySelector("textpath");

// SET
textPath.textContent = "Changing content";
// GET
console.log(textPath.textContent);
```